# OpenTK. Проблема с методом GL.DrawElements

Tags: c#, opentk

Я изучаю openTK по учебнику

Вот ссыль: https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/3-element-buffer-objects.html

Раздел "Element Buffer Objects"

Вроде все сделал как там написано, но когда я ввел последнюю строку кода

```
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
```

то получил несколько ошибок

> CS1503: Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.PrimitiveType" в "OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.All"

> CS1503: Аргумент 3: не удается преобразовать из "OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.PrimitiveType" в "OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.All"

> CS1503: Аргумент 4: не удается преобразовать из "int" в "System.IntPtr"

Ладно, хоть это не так как написано в учебнике, я изменил этот метод на

```
GL.DrawElements(All.Triangles, indices.Length, All.UnsignedInt, (IntPtr)0);
```

потому что это единственное решение, которое я увидел. И эти ошибки пропали, но когда я запустил код, то получил

> System.AccessViolationException: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."

Теперь я не знаю что делать, надеюсь на чью - то помощь, ниже прикрепляю мой код класса Game

```
internal class Game : GameWindow
{
    readonly float[] vertices =
    {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left
    };
    uint[] indices = 
    {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,   // first triangle
        1, 2, 3    // second triangle
    };
    int VertexBufferObject;
    int VertexArrayObject;
    int ElementBufferObject;
    Shader shader;


    public Game(int width, int height, string title) : base(width, height, GraphicsMode.Default, title)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * sizeof(float), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        ElementBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ElementBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indices.Length * sizeof(uint), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        VertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        shader = new Shader("shader.vert", "shader.frag");

        shader.Use();

        //Code goes here
    }
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        shader.Use();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        GL.DrawElements(All.Triangles, indices.Length, All.UnsignedInt, (IntPtr)0);
        //Code goes here.

        SwapBuffers();
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    }
    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);
        // Unbind all the resources by binding the targets to 0/null.
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.UseProgram(0);

        // Delete all the resources.
        GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexBufferObject);
        GL.DeleteVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

        GL.DeleteProgram(shader.Handle);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо это ошибка в учебнике либо там используется более старая версия.
Последним параметром должен быть **indices**, тогда в окне мы увидим искомый  прямоугольник.
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, indices);